# Custom JDBC sink for Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I need to consume a stream of events from Kafka and based on the event type perform a different query. Standard JDBC sink allows to work with a single query, so I need to create a custom sink. Usually, when I need to talk with SQL I'm using some nice wrappers like Slick, Doobie, Jooq, etc. Can I use them with the sink implementation? Somehow, I have a feeling that I should use the plain JDBC driver to avoid serialization issues, am I right?